# Previous Excel instance not getting through IIS

Tags: vb.net, excel, iis

I am using VB.NET to open the Excel files but dont want to create excel object every time.

My code is working perfectly in debug mode, but after publish, it never gets the existing instances and always create new instances which we can see from Task Manager. Here is my code which always returns false in published mode.

My OS is Windows Server 2008. Please guide how to solve this.

```
Function IsExcelRunning() As Boolean
        Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
        On Error Resume Next
        xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
        IsExcelRunning = (Err.Number = 0)
        MyHelper.writeLog("Excel Instance found=" & IsExcelRunning)
        xlApp = Nothing
        Err.Clear()
End Function
```

Here is how I call.

```
  If IsExcelRunning() Then
        excelApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
  Else
       excelApp = Server.CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  End If
```

Comment: Can you please post the code of the GetObject method?

Comment: @varocarbas - `GetObject()` is a VB.NET built-in carried across from legacy VB5/6: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e9waz863(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @Kev Thanks for the info, no idea about that.

Comment: As per Kev's information and link, it seems that your problems might derive from intending to mix up new VB.NET code (Office Interop) with old VB one. As you can see in this MSDN link, all the types are "Object", not "Excel.Application" (Interop). You should either follow the "old" code as suggested by this link, or move to newer .NET one; but don't put everything together.

Answer (score 0):

We used to use Excel Interop and I remember it always being difficult to work with (clunky.) Due to the Interop opening an Excel process and not closing it every time you use it, makes it difficult to work with.

The Interop opens Excel automatically, so all we needed to do was close it. This is what we used to use to kill the Process. Replace YourProcessName with Excel.exe.

```
Dim proc As System.Diagnostics.Process
Dim info As ManagementObject
Dim search As New ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT ProcessId FROM Win32_process WHERE caption = 'YourProcessName'")
For Each info In search.Get()
    Dim TheString As String = info.GetText(TextFormat.Mof).ToString
    proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById(Mid$(TheString, _
                                                    (Len(TheString) - 8), 4))
    proc.CloseMainWindow()
    proc.Refresh()
    If proc.HasExited Then GoTo NoKill
    proc.Kill()
NoKill:
Next
```

You'll need to import

```
Imports System.Management
```

You'll also need to add the reference 'System.Management' to your project.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wkze6zky.aspx for adding a reference to a project.

If you can rather work with CSV, I would suggest you try to. If you are creating the Excel file yourself, try to find a report creator that let's you create / export to Excel. You'll save yourself a lot of time in the long run.

Comment: I am not looking to close the application, but looking to get the same instance to work again instead of closing and opening to save time.

Comment: We tried to find a solution for ages to do that as well. Unfortunately there is almost no control over the Interop and it does start a new process every time it opens or creates an Excel file.